# How do I use .setFormula to insert a formula that has relative references in a vlookup?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the following script to:
1. Copy data from another sheet (it works!)
2. Insert three formulas side by side by side (Works!)
3. Make the cell references in the formula relative, so that when it's in row 2 it references I2, in row 3 it references I3, etc. (Not working)

Presently, it works for the first go around but when I run the script for the next set of data, it starts at row 2 again. I understand it's typed that way, but I want to make the cell references relative to the row it's in.

I am no programmer, and most of this is cribbed from the helpful folks at StackOverflow. I need the I reference to be relative to the row its in, and the A reference to do the same.

```
function CopyDataToNewFile2() {
  const source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1WYXp-S5XoegSnzzC9uRao8uPCyJ6UxNQgOGf3c7DQO0').getSheetByName('Outcome'); // sss = source spreadsheet

  const destination= SpreadsheetApp.openById('1sX6VTyedVLBL57EMSuD7cqUwe9GzoCRajLZhA1ZBJ3Q');
  const target = destination.getSheetByName('Final');
  if (!source || !target)
    throw new Error("Missing required worksheets (sheet names not found)");

const dataToCopy = source.getDataRange().getValues();

   dataToCopy.shift(); // remove header row.
  const startRow = target.getLastRow() + 1;
  const numRows = dataToCopy.length;
  const numColumns = dataToCopy[0].length;
  target
    .getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, numColumns)
    .setValues(dataToCopy)
    .offset(0, numColumns, numRows, 1) // offset is from the top-right cell of the range
    .setFormula('=vlookup($I2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f7_unFqRkI6O2EHBLsNGLRCH5j9rlEXBdVnRLTgS_lM/edit#gid=1203869430","Source_Hours!A:B"),2,false)/$A2')
  .offset(0,1,numRows,1)
  .setFormula('=vlookup($I2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f7_unFqRkI6O2EHBLsNGLRCH5j9rlEXBdVnRLTgS_lM/edit#gid=1203869430","Copy of Other Time Not Included in WLI%!A:B"),2,false)')
  .offset(0,1,numRows,1)
  .setFormula('=sum($AO2,$AN2)');



}
```

If there are 172 rows of data being copied, the first round of copying is accurate. Once I copy another 172 rows by running the script again, it still only references I2-I172, and A2-A172. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use R1C1 format, and `Range#setFormulaR1C1`

Comment: @tehhowch Awesome, thank you so much! I figured it out. I added the following to the bottom of my script:  ````target.getRange(startRow, target.getLastColumn(), numRows, 1).setFormulaR1C1("=SUM(R[0]C[-3]:R[0]C[-2])");````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Once I have enough reputation, I will do so! Thanks!